# How to create function to update columns in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am hoping to create a function that can update the columns in my table.

But it  seems it doesn't work out l. I am pretty new to postgres, and I am wondering if there is a way to do so? The following is what I have so far.

```
Create Table roads(
    intid_ integer,
    muni text,
    alias_ text,
    roadnames text,
    geom geometry);

Insert into roads (roadnames, geom, intid_, alias_)
SELECT 
    trim(student.sc_e911slrn.prefix) || trim(student.sc_e911slrn.name) || trim(student.sc_e911slrn.suffix), 
    geom, objectid, alias
FROM student.sc_e911slrn;

--------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE type student.inter AS (
     roadnames text,
        intid_ int,
        alias_ text,
        muni text,
        ST_Intersection geometry,
        geom geometry);

--< Cursor >--------------------------------------------------------
Create function create_intersections()
    /*returns table student.intersect_roads As $method1$*/
    RETURNS table (
        roadnames text,
        intid_ int,
        alias_ text,
        muni text,
        ST_Intersection geometry,
        geom geometry) As $$

Declare
    return_intersect inter;
    rec_road Record;
    cur_road Cursor()
        For Select intid_, geom, roadnames
        From student.roads;

Begin
    Open cur_road();

    Loop
        fetch cur_road into rec_road;
        exit when not found;

        If ST_Touches(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom) AND
            rec_road.geom != student.roads.geom AND 
            rec_road.intid_ != student.roads.intid_

        Then Update student.intersect_road
             Set st_intersection = ST_Intersection (rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom),
                 intid_ = rec_road.intid_,
                 intersections = rec_road.roadnames|| ' & ' || student.raods.roadnames,
                 alias_ = rec_road.alias_,
                 /*muni = */
                 polyline = ST_Union(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom)
                 RETURNING * into return_intersect;
                 RETURN NEXT;
        End if;
    End Loop;
    Close cur_road;

    RETURN;

End; 
$$ Language plpgsql;
```

So table road is something like this:

```
Intid_     Muni    Alias_           Roadnames            geom
24581722   NULL    CR 52       Coopers Falls road        ...
24581723   NULL    CR 44       Rama road                 ...
```

What I am trying to do is create a table contains intersections at the location where each road intersects `Roadname 1 & Roadname 2` as well as the geometry spatial data for the intersection `ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)`

I also tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_intersections() 
     UPDATE student.intersect_roads AS $$
Declare
Begin
End
$$
```

Which is not working as well.
Any feedbacks would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For a start you've got student.raods in your where clause and your concatenaton, suspect that should be student.roads?

Comment: Thank you OTTA, I just updated the post:)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide DDL not sample data, so nothing in the following is verified. But just indication your intent is to return rows is not sufficient. You need to actually indicate which rows with either return query or return next.

```
Create Function create_intersections()
    returns table student.student.intersect_roads As $method1$

    return_intersect student.student.intersect_roads;   -- <<<< 
    rec_road Record;
    cur_road Cursor(roadname text);
        For Select intid, geom, roadname
        From student.roads
        Where student.raods.roadname != roadname

Begin
    Open cur_road (roadname);


    Loop
        fetch cur_road into rec_road
        exit when not found;

        If ST_Touches(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom) AND
            rec_road.geom != student.roads.geom AND 
            rec_road.intid != student.roads.intid 

        Then Update student.intersect_roads
             Set st_intersection = ST_Intersection (rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom),
                 intid = rec_road.intid,
                 intersections = rec_road.roadname|| ' & ' || student.raods.roadname,
                 alias = rec_road.alias,
                 /*muni = */
                 polyline = ST_Union(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom)
                 returning * into return_intersect ;  --<<<<

                 return next return_intersect ;  --<<<<
        End if;
    End Loop;
    Close cur_road;
    RETURN;                --<<<<
    End; $method1$
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `return_intersect student.student.intersect_roads;   -- <<<<` I don't think we can define the data type as 'student.intersect_roads'?

Comment: And it seems that the `returns table` on the second line is also error out...

Comment: And you still have not provided DDL or sample data and expected results.  Not much I can do without that, please see [ask].